# How to pass multiple parameters from Single Activity to multiple Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

Let’s say I have a

- 1 Activity with a listView called subCategory,
- 3 different Fragment Activities
  DescriptionFragment, 
  EfficacyFragment and
  ImagesFragment
- and 1 Activity called DetailInformation Activity which will implement all the 3 fragments I have.
  List of subcategories will be listed in the subcategory Activity listview. 
  When you select the subcategory from the list,  DetailInformation Activity will be opened containing the 3 fragments.

problem Category List Activity

[image]

Detail Information Activity implementing the 3 Fragments

[image]

- DescriptionFragment will contain detailed description of the selected subcategory
- EfficacyFragment also contain some information about the selected subcategory
- ImageFragment will contain image of the problem
  Whenever the user selected a different subcategory, the information displayed will also vary. 
  My question is that how can I pass (3 parameters – MainCategoryName, subCategoryName, and problemName) of the selected subcategory to each Fragment so that each fragment will display information about the subcategory.

I have seen different approaches like using bundle and using interface and I couldn’t understand non-of them. SO PLS I need HELP Guys!!!

Comment: You must endeavor to understand the patterns you've said you've already seen as they are the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass params by defining new instance in your fragments as below :

```
public class FragmentA extends BaseFragment {

View view;
PreferencesManager pm;

@BindView(R.id.textview1)
TextView textView1;


public static FragmentA newInstance(String param1,String param2,String param3) {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    FragmentA fragment = new FragmentA();
    args.putString("param1", param1);
    args.putString("param2", param2);
    args.putString("param3, param3);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        if (getArguments().size() > 0) {
            param1= getArguments().getString("param1");
            param2= getArguments().getString("param2");
            param3= getArguments().getString("param3");

        }
    }
    return view;
}
```

}

This is how you replace your fragment :

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_main, FragmentA.newInstance(param1,param2,param3))
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
```

Comment: where exactly do i replace my fragment?? Thanks!

Comment: It could be used for FragmentTabs ( Description , Efficiency, Images ) or could be used to load FragmentCategory. It depends on you for which fragment you want to pass the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

send data from your activity class:

`YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment ();
    fragment.setArguments(data);`

Receive data in fragment class:

`Bundle bundle=getArguments();`